# Android: format string and add bold style

Tags: java, android, string, format

I have a string in my resource:

```
<string name="region"><b>Region:</b> %1$s</string>
```

I am trying to set this text to a textview:

```
tvRegion.setText(Html.fromHtml(R.string.region, "France"));
```

The problem is that the string "region" is not bold !

Comment: Can you check if returned String is correct? Maybe `b` is escaped?

Answer (score 8):

From [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML):

> Sometimes you may want to create a styled text resource that is also used as a format string. Normally, this won't work because the `String.format(String, Object...)` method will strip all the style information from the string. The work-around to this is to write the HTML tags **with escaped entities**, which are then recovered with `fromHtml(String)`, after the formatting takes place.

You need to HTML-escape the opening bracket of html tags, when inserting it in any xml resource file.

```
<string name="region">&lt;b>Region:&lt;/b> %1$s</string>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can do that in xml:

```
<string name="region"><![CDATA[<b>Region:</b> %1$s]]></string>
```

And the java code:

```
String str = getString(R.string.action_about_msg, "France");
tvRegion.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML text directly in **`Html.fromHtml()`** method.. try this way..

```
tvRegion.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + yourtext+ "</b>" + "Other text.."));
```

with this you can style your string with HTML tags.. as you want..